# Datatype for storing continous time counter?

Tags: mysql, types

I need to store a time counter of how long a person has spent on mysite So if i logon today for 20 minutes and tomorrow for 1 hr then the counter should be 1 hour, 20 minutes. So the ideal format should be: YY:DD:HH:MM (Years:Days:Hours:Minutes). How to store this? I cant see this being calculated at runtime because after a lik 50 logins the system will need to always re-calculate the time from 0 up. So prefer to have this calculated after each logout and written to the user_table but I cant figure out a good data type except varchar? DB is mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seconds`, that'll be traduced in the integer type that you consider appropiate.

Then, you can transform this value to a date format.

That's what the engine does internally actually, AFAIK.

Good luck!

Comment: Seconds is too small and the number will grow fast. Hence I am not counting a second but keeping minute as the smallest data. But there is no seconds datatype? that means an int datatype correct or a bigint i guess if seconds are used?

Comment: it's ok, you define the base. You can use minutes. Integer will be the format for seconds, minutes, or whatever you want to use as basic unit of information. Just use an unsigned value. Here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html you'll find the max values. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since it does not appear that MySQL 5.5 supports an SQL standard INTERVAL type, I suggest using a numeric type that stores the number of minutes in aggregate.  When you need to present the value, call a function to convert the number of minutes into an interval in days, hours and minutes as a string.

Comment: so bigint will be the best thinking long term?

Comment: Possibly, though it is relatively unlikely that many people will accumulate 68 years of time on your system, and a 32-bit (signed) integer is big enough to hold that length of time in seconds - let alone minutes (which would require over 4,000 years of accumulated time on your system to overflow!).  OTOH, if you want to aggregate times logged onto your system across 500 million or so users, then bigint is appropriate.